# Postfix: disable deliver to local user accounts

Tags: postfix

I'm running postfix+dovecot, and currently postfix is delivering to local accounts:

```
local_recipient_maps = proxy:unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps
```

The spammers have found one of my user's accounts and the deluge is getting problematic. What I'd like to know is how to disable local delivery to this one UID (we'll call it 'joeuser').

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set hash map with `check_recipient_access` in `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` to restrict mail delivery to certain users:

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf:
   smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
      ...
      check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/access_recipient
      ...

/etc/postfix/access_recipient:
   joeuser@youdomain.com REJECT
```

Comment: Thanks, Alex. When I add the email addy to that file, postmap'ed it and reload postfix, I still get deliveries to it. :/  The line looks like this: smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated permit_mynetworks reject_unauth_destination check_policy_service unix:private/policy permit check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/access_recipient.  However, when I put this as the first condition on the line, it started working.

Comment: @MikeC all checks in `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` applied in order they are written and first one which returns PERMIT or REJECT wins, all remaining checks are skipped.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is to simply forward the mail for this specific user to /dev/null.

Edit `/etc/aliases` and insert a line that looks like this

```
joeuser: /dev/null
```

Save, quit and execute this command: `newaliases`

After that, postfix will just get rid of e-mail sent to that account rather than delivering it locally - see maillog example:

```
Apr 20 08:49:50 clustermx04 postfix/qmgr[31542]: 8BE7A720716: from=<mail@removed>, size=881, nrcpt=1 (queue active)

Apr 20 08:49:50 clustermx04 postfix/local[26205]: 8BE7A720716: to=<testaccount@removed.net>, relay=local, delay=0.38, delays=0.38/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to file: /dev/null)

Apr 20 08:49:50 clustermx04 postfix/qmgr[31542]: 8BE7A720716: removed
```

Comment: Thanks, Frands. This also works well. I do like the idea of sending back a 500 message to the sender that the recip doesn't exist. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to AlexD's answer above, it is necessary to actually create the postfix db file from the text file that is mentioned by running `postmap /etc/postfix/access_recipient`. Otherwise postfix will complain that it can't find access_recipient.db and will block every mail for any user.

More details can be found here: http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html

(Sorry, I can't comment yet here, hence a full answer).